# set configuration properties in sonar

Tags: sonarqube

Maybe, this question is silly but I'm very new. I try to search without luck.

I got two errors when building maven project with sonar:

```
   No information about coverage per test.
```

Although I had test code and these testing classes cover the code.

```
The global property 'sonar.doxygen.deploymentPath' is not set. Set it in SONAR and run another analysis.
```

I dont know it should be set where in sonar server. I set in web.xml or sonar-server.properties but it does not work.

Thanks.

Comment: Which Sonar plugins are you using ? What's the language of the project you're analysing ?

Comment: I want to add Doxygen and my project is developed by java

Answer (score 0):

About the first warning message this is not an error but a warning : since Sonar 3.5 this is possible to get the code coverage relating to each unit test. Here the message just says that this feature is not activated which is expected by default. Nevertheless I do agree that this warning message can be misleading.

About the second error message, I don't know the doxygen plugin but the message seems to be pretty clear : the sonar.doxygen.deploymentPath property has not be defined. See the plugin documentation : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Doxygen+Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. There is no war folder anymore since the sonarqube has given up tomcat support
2. The doxygen plugin is not implemented to upload the files in to the sonarqube server &/ installation, which means it only can be done by referencing the path inside your installation, e.g.:

   1. run "mvn install sonar:sonar" in your project "/root/test.example.sonar.com"
   2. in sonarqube set the cfg-key "sonar.doxygen.deploymentPath" the value: "/root/sonarqube-4.1.1/web/" and the cfg-key "sonar.doxygen.deploymentUrl" the value: "http://:9000"
   3. have fun with your doxygen

---

Remember that the plugin will only be run through your mvn cmd, refreshing the page only will not do the job, you will have to analyse again after each cfg set :/

Check the file system and folder permission